# Angular $HTTP Error Handler

Tags: angularjs, http, error-handling

Below is an example of a pretty crude way i'm currently handling a a HTTP call which is taking too long.

If it takes more than 3 seconds, re-fire, and if this fails 4 times than exit.

While it works, I don't wish to create every HTTP request like this as it is too much code for one call.

Is there a way of applying this globally?

I'm not sure if an interceptor is suitable for this case, as I need the error handle to kick in after the HTTP call takes too long, rather than when it receives a bad response from the server.

I would also need this to apply to requests for partial views.

Code:

```
     var errorCount = 0;           

            function someFunction() {

               var startTime = new Date().getTime();

               var deferred = $q.defer();

               var url = 'some url';

               $http.get(url, {cache: true, timeout: 3000}).success(function(response) {

                deferred.resolve(response);

            }).error(function(result, status, header, config) {

                var respTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;

                  if( respTime >= config.timeout ){

                        errorCount +=1;

                        if ( errorCount > 3) {

                            errorCount = 0;

                            deferred.reject(result);

                        } else {

                            getCountries();
                        };

                    } else{

                        deferred.reject(error);

                    };

            });

            return deferred.promise;

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is what I ended up doing.

Probably not the best way but maybe someone will find it useful too!

So using an interceptor I configure all outgoing HTTP requests to abort after 3 seconds, and configure any responses which have a status of 'abort' (which is a status of '-1' I think) to retry 3 times.

Code:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('InterceptModule', []);

angular
    .module('InterceptModule')
    .factory('myInterceptor', myInterceptor);


myInterceptor.$inject = ['$q', '$injector','$cookies']


function myInterceptor($q,$injector,$cookies) {

    var errorCount = 0;

    var service = {

        responseError: responseError,
        request      :  request

    };

    return service;


    //////////

    /* this function is where tell the request to re-fire if it
     * has been aborted.
     *
    */

    function responseError(response) {

            if ( response.status == -1 ) {

                var deferred = $q.defer();

                var firstResponse = response;

                var url = response.config.url;

                var $http = $injector.get('$http');

                    $http.get(url, {cache: true}).then(function(response) {

                        deferred.resolve(response);

                    }, function(result, status, header, config) {

                        if ( status == -1 ) {

                            errorCount += 1;

                            if ( errorCount > 3 ) {

                                errorCount = 0;

                                deferred.reject(result);

                            } else {

                                responseError(firstResponse);

                            }

                        };

                        deferred.reject(result);

                    });



                return deferred.promise;

            };/* if */


            return $q.reject(response);


    };


   /** 
     * this function is where we configure our outgoing http requests
     * to abort if they take longer than 3 seconds.
     *
    */

    function request(config) {

            config.timeout = 3000;

        return config;

    };




}/* service */      


})();
```

Inject our intercept module

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ['InterceptModule']);
```

Then push our interceptor in our config

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
```